# select img based on the title only if certain string is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var no_images2 = $j("img[title='Click to enlarge image no_photo.jpg']").parent();
$j(no_images2).css('pointer-events','none');

var no_images3 = $j("img[title='Click to enlarge image no_photo1.jpg']").parent();
$j(no_images3).css('pointer-events','none');
```

I am using this snippet to select the parent div of the image with those titles, but now I need to have more images, like this with the `no_photo.jpg` on it, but it is going to be now also with numbers like: 1no_photo.jpg, 4no_photo.jpg etc..

Is there a way to select the image in jquery where in its title there is a string no_photo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can. Try this code :

```
var no_images = $("img[title*='no_photo']").parent();
$(no_images).css('pointer-events','none');
```

And have a look to the [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/?s=selector).

Comment: If I could help you, you can validate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var no_images2 = $j("img[title=^'Click to enlarge image']").parent();
```

or

```
var no_images2 = $j("img[title=$'1no_photo.jpg']").parent();
```

Check out the [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors.